# I need a correction for my php codings of the following?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$isptc = gethostbyaddr($ip);
$ispoh = preg_split("/./", $isptc);
$xy = count($ispoh);
$x = $xy - 1;
$y = $xy - 2;
$i = $xy - 3;
$ispp = $ispoh[$i];
$isp = $ispoh[$y] . "." . $ispoh[$x];
echo"<b>ip: $ip</b><br>";
echo"<b>isp: $ispp$isp</b>";
?>
```

In this above mentioned codings, i didn't get the output from $ispp and $isp.

Comment: What do you get when you `var_dump($isptc)` and `var_dump($ispoh)`

Comment: Not all IPs have a reverse mapping (ip->name). Check if the IP you're trying this on actually does have a reverse PTR record defined. If not, gethostbyaddr can't return anything.

Comment: when i put var_dump($istpc) i got the following...."string(15) "117.199.129.184""......

Comment: After that i put var_dump($ispoh) it gives the following..,"array(16) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(0) "" [6]=> string(0) "" [7]=> string(0) "" [8]=> string(0) "" [9]=> string(0) "" [10]=> string(0) "" [11]=> string(0) "" [12]=> string(0) "" [13]=> string(0) "" [14]=> string(0) "" [15]=> string(0) "" } "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Got an answers from the following PHP Codings....

```
<?php

$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$url=file_get_contents("http://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/$ip");

preg_match_all('/<th>(.*?)<\/th><td>(.*?)<\/td>/s',$url,$output,PREG_SET_ORDER);

$isp=$output[1][2];

$city=$output[9][2];

$state=$output[8][2];

$zipcode=$output[12][2];

$country=$output[7][2];

?>
<body>
<table align="center">
<tr><td>ISP :</td><td><?php echo $isp;?></td></tr>
<tr><td>City :</td><td><?php echo $city;?></td></tr>
<tr><td>State :</td><td><?php echo $state;?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Zipcode :</td><td><?php echo $zipcode;?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Country :</td><td><?php echo $country;?></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is using `preg_split("/./")`. That will split the string on **any** character, not dots (because you didn't regex-escape the dot). Instead use:

```
$ispoh = explode(".", $isptc);
```

For the following code, I don't really know. That looks a bit obfuscated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.,i got only $ispp.,not $isp...i want the both output $ispp and $isp...

Comment: Your variable names are ugly. And there might simply be no data in $ispooho. (Also, you give too few upvotes on SO.)

Comment: what i do for get an Internet Service Provider(ISP)...If you have the answer for it....

Comment: an whois will bring up details, but is hardly automatable.

Answer (score 0):

use `explode()` instead.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$isptc = gethostbyaddr($ip);

$isp = array_shift(explode(".", $isptc));

echo"<b>ip: $ip</b><br>";
echo"<b>isp: $isp</b>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your preg_split's period:

```
$ispoh = preg_split("/\./", $isptc);
```